Websocket error when running "streamlit hello" on localhost
Streamlit hello opens up a browser with a silhouette of some flashing page elements, kind of looks like it's trying to load but can't connect.  The command line I used to run streamlit hello shows a websocket error. Chrome also shows a websocket error in the developer tab.  The error messages in cmd and the browser both repeat continuously, reoccurring every few seconds while the process runs.
cmd:
streamlit hello

browser:
http://localhost:8501/

Command line error:
2024-11-10 12:57:40.144 Uncaught exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myUsername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tornado\http1connection.py", line 278, in _read_message
    delegate.finish()
  File "C:\Users\myUsername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tornado\routing.py", line 268, in finish
    self.delegate.finish()
  File "C:\Users\myUsername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 2399, in finish
    self.execute()
  File "C:\Users\myUsername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 2421, in execute
    self.handler = self.handler_class(
  File "C:\Users\myUsername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tornado\websocket.py", line 220, in __init__
    super().__init__(application, request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\myUsername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 214, in __init__
    super().__init__()
  File "C:\Users\myUsername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\typing.py", line 1422, in _no_init_or_replace_init
    cls.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: WebSocketHandler.__init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'application' and 'request'

Chrome developer tab error:
main.754d974e.js:19 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8501/\_stcore/stream' failed:
connectToWebSocket @ main.754d974e.js:19

WebsocketConnection WebSocket onerror
a @ mainl.754d974e.js:10

I am using Python 3.10.  Streamlit is a fresh install with pip, which I also updated.
I am running WLS Ubuntu (Linux subsystem) on my machine, but I don't think that should be relevant since Python is installed on windows and all the commands and browsers I am using are on my main windows system.
I tried turning off Norton antivirus stuff. I tried turning off all Chrome extensions and also tried the same in Edge. I tried creating a Python virtual environment.  I tried running the command prompt as an administrator.
I did google the error message and that is how I found the list of resolutions that I mentioned as having already tried. Many of the suggestions relate to writing custom code, but I'm just executing the built-in "hello world" feature of streamlit without any custom work. I don't see how TLS could be the cause as I'm not using https to connect in the browser. The closest thing to my error that I found was the below, but it does not lead to a resolution: github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/9140
This is some kind of basic environment setup issue I feel, because it is a built-in hello world function within streamlit.
Here is how I created and setup my virtual environment:
python -m venv strl_venv
strl_venv\Scripts\activate.bat
pip install streamlit
python -m streamlit hello

This did not solve the problem.

I just tried to replicate this - no issues - maybe try running in a new virtual environment.

Just retried the virtual environment and posted the commands I used for it.

I reinstalled python 3.13 and the software and it works.  Whatever doesn't work in 3.10 works fine in 3.13.

Cool! You may provide the answer and accept it. Please, if possible, give more detail on why it worked with a higher version and not with 3.10. For reference, here's the streamlit/hello repo.
